# Sound board beeping compulsively after installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound, headphones

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a Packard Bell EasyNote MV85-100 that was previously running WinXP. Pretty swift and no errors during install, but as soon as Ubuntu loads the sound board goes bonkers and starts issuing a compulsive beeping sound (kind of like Morse code); this is on full volume, after 5 minutes my head was cracking. I have tried to mute the sound, connect headphones and microphone, but nothing shuts the beeping off. In the Sound Settings menu there are two devices listed: the board and the headphones, with the later blinking to the rhythm of the beep.

Any hints on how to tame this soundboard are welcome. Even just muting the sound would be an improvement. Thanks.

Comment: I went through the ordeal of turning this laptop on again to tried a few more things. I ran the updates and got about 100 packages anew; I requested a search for proprietary drivers and got a driver for the DVD. I restarted it but the compulsive beeping remains.

Comment: I booted Debain 7.0.0 on this laptop and there are no  issues with the soundboard. It seems this issue is only affecting the kernel 3.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by installing the 3.2 kernel package and then setting it as the default GRUB option.