# How to install 12.04 with kernel 3.2?

Tags: 12.04, kernel

A few days ago I reported [a strange issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/352618/sound-board-beeping-compulsively-after-installing-ubuntu-12-04) with an old laptop after installing 12.04. I now know this is a problem with the kernel module presently supporting 12.04 (3.8), since with kernel 3.2 the laptop behaves regularly (booting Debian Wheezy).

Knowing that 12.04 was initially released with kernel 3.2, I would like to try that first version on this laptop, but presently one can only download 12.04.3. So the question is to either obtain the first 12.04 release or revert 12.04.3 back to kernel 3.2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install the Linux 3.2 kernel, install the linux-image-3.2.0-23-generic package. Then follow the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version).

Comment: Well, I installed that package but GRUB is not showing up at boot. I'll try to tweak it somehow.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa have you followed the steps listed at the end of my answer? "Then follow the steps here".

Comment: The laptop wasn't booting with the Shift key pressed. Going through [this guide][1] eventually got me there. Thanks. [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/68547/editing-the-default-boot-item-in-grub-menu-a-definitive-answer

Answer (score 1):

**There are possible two ways to get `linux-kernel 3.2.x`**

- Since you can download only 12.04.3 from official site, one way is to download Ubuntu 12.04 searching the torrents. If you don't get, I'll create one for you, I've Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.04.2 images of x86 and x64 bits.
- You can install Kernel 3.2.x from repository. Just search : `Linux 3.2` in [Synaptic](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto) you'll get a list of kernels from there you can install Kernel `3.2.x`

Reply if you need further assistance..

Answer (score 0):

You can install the original 12.04. Search here, at the bottom of the page:
[Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (Precise Pangolin)](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.0/)

With that, you can update and Ubuntu will keep the 3.2.x kernel.

Comment: The newer versions of the kernel will be installed during updates, unless one removes the kernel from being updated.

Comment: Are you sure? When I was on Ubuntu 12.04, I updated and updated, with constats kernel updates, and all the time it was 3.2,even if the system was already in version 12.04.1 or 12.04.2, etc.

Comment: I think it's because 12.04 is LTS (I use 13.04)