# How to fix flickering sound

Tags: sound

I switched completely to Ubuntu 12.04  everything is fine instead when I play any track or video, the visual performance is good but the sounds flickers always and when I try to increase the volume it starts to flicker more. I installed Ubuntu restricted extras, checked my hardware, hardware drivers etc.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had [a similar issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/352618/sound-board-beeping-compulsively-after-installing-ubuntu-12-04) with 12.04.3 on an old laptop; it seems that kernel 3.8 struggles with some soundboards. I suggest you try installing kernel 3.2 (package *linux-image-3.2.0-23-generic*) and set it up to boot by default. Check out [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68547/editing-the-default-boot-item-in-grub-menu-a-definitive-answer) for details.

Comment: thank you Luis but, as i am new to Ubuntu 12.04 its hard for me to understand, i carried on with the guide you shared but i didn't get anything then also i tried, still my problem is unsolved please will u help me with easier ways.            thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems when using a USB DAC on an unpowered usb hub.  Plugging the DAC straight into my laptop made it go away.

If you're not using an internal soundcard, consider whether your device is getting sufficient power, at least in my case, the DAC was just rebooting several times per second.